# What does "row" mean in two-row hops/malt

Tags: hops, grain, malt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between 2-row and 6-row malt?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/367/whats-the-difference-between-2-row-and-6-row-malt)

And why should I care?

Comment: I voted to close.

Comment: Don't close, this is an interesting question that I'd like to see answered too.  And it's not a dupe, the original question explained the difference as an effect on brewing, now how it actually got its name.

Comment: Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

I had to dig quickly in case this votes to close (why?), but here's your answer:

Why is 2-Row more plump, generally, than 6-Row? The two types of malting barley get their name from the way the kernels grow on the stalk. Two rows of kernels grow on a 2-Row stalk and six rows of kernels grow on a 6-Row stalk. The 2-row kernels simply have more room. The picture at the top shows the size of the two types in relation to each other.

Source: http://www.brewingwithbriess.com/Malting101/The_Row_Less_Traveled.htm